# MyFirstPortlet-portlet-6.1.1.1.war does not support this version of Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, blacklist

I'm learning portlets and at the moment I'm not able to run my portlet in Liferay.
When I want to deploy my portlet on Liferay, in my console I receive this messages:

```
com.liferay.portal.deploy.auto.PortletAutoDeployListener.deploy(PortletAutoDeployListener.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.deploy(AutoDeployDir.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.processFile(AutoDeployDir.java:211)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployDir.scanDirectory(AutoDeployDir.java:275)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner.run(AutoDeployScanner.java:58)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployException: MyFirstPortlet-portlet-6.1.1.1.war does not support this version of Liferay
    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.deployFile(BaseDeployer.java:902)
    at com.liferay.portal.tools.deploy.BaseDeployer.autoDeploy(BaseDeployer.java:213)
    ... 6 more
07:16:25,174 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:224] Add MyFirstPortlet-portlet-6.1.1.1.war to the blacklist
```

I'm using the bundle *liferay-portal-tomcat-6.2-ce-ga4*

Do I need another version of Liferay?

Comment: What version of liferay are you using?

Comment: liferay-portal-tomcat-6.2-ce-ga4.

Comment: And the portlet you are deploying is built using Liferay 6.1, which is not compatible.

Comment: This is strange for me. Shall I install the Lilferay Plugins SDK for 6.2?

Comment: Create new portlet in current portal instance. Move files of old portlet to the newly created portlet and deploy again.

Comment: Have you resolved it now?

Comment: No. Now I tried to change the Plugins SDK .Previosusly when I was creating the Liferay Plugin Project it was select by default for the Plugins SDK : lifefary-plugins-sdk-6.1.1 and now I changed to liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2

Comment: but when I press finish this error comes out : >[Console output redirected to file:D:\new\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.liferay.ide.sdk.core\sdk.log] ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.

Comment: The java would be not on specified path.

Comment: I've checked, and the the path is correct unfortunately

Comment: Have you defined the environment variable for JAVA_HOME?

Comment: yes, I did. Strangely if I select liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1 is no error. but if I choose liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2 error about JAVA_HOME pops-up.

Comment: The `JAVA_HOME` variable should point to the directory above `bin`

Comment: the path is this: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin

Comment: I can't figure out what is wrong. do you know another alternative to run/study/practice Portlets?

Comment: To make it more clear: `JAVA_HOME` should be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60` _without the `bin`_.

Comment: Great job  @TobiasLiefke . Thank you. I've been using jdk for almost a year with eclipse and I never had this problem. As I recall I saw other toturials that make the path with _bin_ .

Answer (score -1):

Just remove "liferay-versions" property from "liferay-versions=6.1.20.xml" file and restart the server.It will solve your problem

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This answer would be better with a little explanation - how does this address the question? Presumably this property exists for a reason, so what other implications does removing it have? Looking at the comments, it seems that the OP's issue was resolved with correctly setting `JAVA_HOME`, so perhaps this isn't really relevant in this case?